# Unable to install tensorflow v1 Python package in Docker image

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, pip, dockerfile

I am trying to install tensorflow<2.0,>=1.15 pip package during the Docker build. I am not able to build it, and I am getting this error in my terminal during the pip installation:

```
 > [12/12] RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt:                                                                                                                     
#16 0.488 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow<2.0,>=1.15 (from versions: none)                                                                
#16 0.489 ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow<2.0,>=1.15
```

---

**To replicate the error:**

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-buster
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y unzip
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y python-all-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libexiv2-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libboost-python-dev
RUN apt-get install -y wget

COPY . /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

requirements.txt:

```
tensorflow>=1.15,<2.0
```

---

- I have tried to build FROM (first line in the Dockerfile) other Python versions, either 3.7 or lower, never newer. Still the same result.
- I use Docker Desktop for Mac M1 version 4.3.2, Engine version 20.10.11.
- When I run it on Fedora Linux, I can build it successfully.

I suspect that this can be Docker-related. There might be a difference between Docker Desktop and Docker for Linux. But I might be doing something wrong.

Have some of you folks ever encountered the same error? How did you solve this? Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Tried to replicate it, and the Dockerfile you wrote down seems to work for me. (Also Macos but not with M1 processor)

But what is weird in your case is the error: 
No matching distribution found for tensorflow<2.0,>=1.15   

On a first glance this does not seem like it's "hardware" related, more than the pip cannot find the correct version of the package? Can you just for sanity reasons add on the last line:

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir 'tensorflow==1.15'

Just to exclude the wrong package version in the requirements file

Comment: Hey J.D. thanks for your comment. I tried and got the same error. My colleague got back to me saying he did not get this error on his Windows. I assume this is an M1 problem then :/.

Comment: Tensorflow 1.x does not support on Mac M1 chip. It is recommended to install Tensorflow>=2.5 on Mac M1. Thanks!

Comment: @TFer thanks for the comment. Well, I thought that maybe since it Linux Docker container it would work. I assume then that this is a hardware-related matter. Do you know if it is written somewhere in docs that v1 does not work with M1?

Comment: Take a look at this release notes from Mac https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/releases

Comment: @TFer, I'll approve it if you post an answer since this is a valid response. The answer can help more people searching for the same answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tensorflow 1.x does not support the Mac M1 chip. It is recommended to install Tensorflow >=2.5 on Mac M1

Take a look at these release notes from Mac Tensorflow:

https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/releases